# ¿Como puedo cambiar el icono de un app clonada en la vista minimizada?

Tags: android, android-studio

Este icono NO se cambia después de realizar el image asset

[image: imagen1]

Este icono no se cambia incluso después de realizar todo el image asset
[image: imagen 2]

Comment: Tome un proyecto de github y lo clone en android studio, luego realize un Asset Image  y subi un nuevo icono con el ICON TYPE: LAUNCHER ICONS (ADAPTATIVE AND LEGACY)

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir cosas como lo que pusiste en el comentario. Usa el enlace editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas. Y por favor, incluye el código asociado a la operación que mencionas (asset image? cómo lo hiciste? cómo incluiste el nuevo recurso?) Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Los dos son diferentes, a que deseas cambiarlo no entiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinicia tu telefono, aveces no lo actualiza porque se queda en cache con los viejos recursos, a mi tambien me paso. tambien si usas http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ te facilita todo, solo tienes que subir tu icono y cuando descargues tu archivo ZIP pegar a esas carpetas a tu carpeta RES de android studio y sobreescrir las anteriores carpetas.

Answer (score 0):

Aveces android studio no reemplaza los iconos de todas las carpetas. Cambia el explorador a modo Proyecto y revisa manualmente todas las versiones de las carpetas drawable y mipmap. Seguramente ahí vas a encontrar el archivo que el image asset no supo reemplazar.